# Does the title filter work differently per site?

Tags: support, title, quality-filter

How did this recent "[UserControl inside Placeholder good/bad? + Postback **problem**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/129920/usercontrol-inside-placeholder-good-bad-postback-problem)" question on Programmers survive the filter? Or do we not have one, and I just made everyone's life there a little bit more difficult?

Πρόβλημα?

Comment: [It seems that it indeed does; http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/129935/problem-problem-problem](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YCs2A.png)

Comment: @Matt Yeap I know; http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=problem

Comment: Although technically *problem* is only restricted in titles; so http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3aproblem would be more appropiate

Comment: @Matt I was bored to type, and the top results have "problem" in title, so it was good enough, specially for a Friday...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is different per-site.  Each site has it's own community, which comes with distinct content and distinct needs and problems - so we have settings per-site to handle that (hundreds of them, though many are often defaults).

Some other examples of site settings we need/use to illustrate:

- Site name
- If MathJax is enabled
- Content folder on the CDN
- Contact email
- ...500 others...

Also keep in mind that **most settings are there for Stack Overflow**, with the global network defaults being set for the SE 2.0 (all other sites) level of things.  Stack Overflow is *incredibly* larger than the next biggest site (by over 25x) and that comes with unique issues, we call these "big city problems".

Comment: Something tells me it has nothing to do with the distinct needs and problems and you are just trying to confuse our attempts to beat the filter... :P

Comment: @Zaphod - These aren't the filters you're looking for...